# How do I force Wubi to download and install 32 bit version?

Tags: wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu Natty beta 2 32bit with WUBI, but whenever I try to install it always tries to download 64 bit version.

How do I ensure that it downloads 32 bit instead of 64 bit?

Comment: @bcbc I don't know if having an accepted answer really matters. The other question has an upvoted answer that says basicly the same thing you said in your answer to this question. But I agree with you, the other question should be duped to this one, since it's older, has more upvotes and better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wubi chooses 64-bit automatically if you have a 64-bit CPU. You can override it with the command line option `--32bit`. This option is required even if you download the 32-bit desktop CD ISO yourself and place it in the same folder as wubi.exe before running.

See the [Wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Why_is_the_AMD64_version_of_Ubuntu_being_downloaded_and_installed.3F) for more info.

When you are installing a beta version of Ubuntu, the CD images and therefore the checksums change frequently, so even if you have the 32 bit ISO it may still reject it. If you are running from a CD, disconnect from the internet or use --skipmd5check to bypass this check (in this case you should make sure you have previously run the md5 check yourself). This is not recommended for non-beta installs, in which case you should let Wubi run the MD5 check.

Answer (score 0):

Put the 32bit ISO in the same directory as Wubi.exe. You can also install magicdisk / deamontools and mount the ISO (Windows is primitive and cannot do this alone), and run the installer there.

I suggest you resize your partitions and make free space for Ubuntu to install a real Ubuntu. This will run better as it will not be affected by NTFS fragmenting the wubi disk file but is also far easier to troubleshoot as you can boot to live CD and access the partitions with ease.

Comment: Doesn't work, it still tries to download a 64bit version.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after disabling internet connection and then having ISO file and wubi file in the same folder.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you should possibly write a bug report so it can be addressed prior to release

Comment: @August This post *is* by the author. It's [quite appropriate for the OP to answer their own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) in this way. Furthermore, if someone else had answered with this information (saying to turn off the Internet connection and install with the ISO image and the Wubi installer executable in the same folder), this would still be a perfectly good answer. (In contrast, this is not a comment--if this had been posted as a comment, I would comment asking that it be re-posted as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

**OFFLINE INSTALLATION:**

1. DISABLE INTERNET
2. MOUNT 32BIT ISO IN WINDOWS VIRTUAL DRIVE (no additional software is required in the case of windows 8)
3. COPY THE wubi.exe TO SOME OTHER DRIVE; FOR EXMAPLE E:\WUBI-INSTALLER
4. OPEN COMMAND PROMPT (ADMIN)
5. CHANGE DIRECTORY TO E:\WUBI-INSTALLER (i.e. the location in your PC where the installer is copied)
6. USE THE FOLLOWING COMMAND TO TARGET TO 32BIT MOUNTED IMAGE:

   ```
     wubi.exe --force-wubi --32bit
   ```

(with this step, the installer will automatically detect and use the mounted ISO image)

COMPLETE THE INSTALLATION

IMPORTANT NOTES:- USE THE wubi.exe FROM THE SAME ISO PACKAGE WHICH YOU'RE USING FOR THE INSTALLATION. Using this method, you can install the 32 bit version of ubuntu inside windows using the downloaded ISO image.

have a nice day

sunny

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug. Actually I also tried to download and I downloaded 32 bit and it becomes 64 bit amd. But I am sure that my computer has 32 bit. It drives me crazy. So, finally, I saw the answer and will try to disconnect from internet as well.

Comment: It's not a bug. You may be running 32bit windows, but it doesn't mean your computer has a 32bit architecture. Post your chip spec or google it online and you'll see it is right.