# Wubi Windows installer downloads wrong Ubuntu image

Tags: 11.04, windows-7, wubi

I downloaded offical Ubuntu Wubi installer as I wanted to install Ubuntu besides my Windows 7 setup.
I launched it and noticed that it started download AMD 64 bit Ubuntu ISO, while I'm on Intel and running 32bit Windows. I canceled operation.

How can I tell Wubi installer which Ubuntu system I want?

Comment: ok I found similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35879/how-do-i-force-wubi-to-download-and-install-32-bit-version though I expected more smart installer as under my current pc configuration it's very unlikely that anyone would like to install 64bit AMD version.

Comment: Well, the 64-bit version often out performs the 32-bit version (especially on newer systems with a lot of memory).  Given that it is still possible to run 32-bit applications (the same as you can with 64-bit Windows), it is a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 3):

Whether your windows installation is 32-bit or 64-bit does not matter for Ubuntu since it's not dependent on windows. Do not get confused by the `amd` word in `amd64`, it's just a marketing name that refers to the same architecture: 64-bit (well, I may not be fully technically correct here, but you can expect an `amd64` Ubuntu image to run on Intel machines). `i386` is used for 32-bit  stuff. If Wubi detects that you've a 64-bit capable processor, it downloads the 64-bit version.

If you really want to force the installation of a 32-bit image, see [How do I force Wubi to download and install 32 bit version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35879/6969)