# 64 bits OS on a 32 bits laptop computer

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi Windows installer downloads wrong Ubuntu image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63499/wubi-windows-installer-downloads-wrong-ubuntu-image)

My computer has a 32 bits processor, when I install from a clean version Ubuntu 11.10, I download a 32 version, but wubi request me a 64 bit, I don't know by a agree with this and now I have a 64 bits Ubuntu on a 32 bits processor with a lot of errors how can I fix this since I try later to installed again and happened the same.

Comment: If it runs at all, your CPU is actually 64-bit. Exactly what is the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to run x86_64 linux version on a x686 CPU. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214403/476681).

Comment: thanks, in fact was working, but I allready did a full instalation of ubuntu 32 bits and now i working great!!! thanks to all