# How can I tell if I have 32-bit version of Ubuntu if I'm installing using the Windows installer?

Tags: installation

I choose to install Ubuntu from Windows installer. My question is I don't know whether it is a 64-bit version 32bit version. Could any body tell me what version it is?  What I want is 32-bit version cause I have a 32-bit CPU

Comment: Possible duplicate Question See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/35879/how-do-i-force-wubi-to-download-and-install-32-bit-version

Answer (score 1):

I assume that a Wubi Ubuntu is still Ubuntu, so the answers to this question should work for you: [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/41332/52923)

I would suggest going with the second method outlined in the "checked" answer which I have copied below.

Open a terminal window and then enter and run the command `file /sbin/init`
**Note:** You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.

If you have the 32-bit version of Ubuntu the result should contain `ELF 32-bit` as in the example below.

> /sbin/init: ELF **32-bit** LSB shared object, **Intel 80386**, version 1 (SYSV) ...

If you have the 64-bit version of Ubuntu the result should contain `ELF 64-bit` as shown below.

> /sbin/init: ELF **64-bit** LSB shared object, **x86-64**, version 1 (SYSV) ...