# Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop 32bit

Tags: installation, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force Wubi to download and install 32 bit version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35879/how-do-i-force-wubi-to-download-and-install-32-bit-version)

I want to instal ubuntu with windows installer. The probles is that I can not select to be installed on 32 bit. How can I do that, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the 32-bits ISO [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) and put it in the same folder you put Wubi.exe, wubi should detect the ISO and allow you to install 32 bits.